# IntelliJ IDEA hangs while "Finished, saving caches"

Tags: intellij-idea

Each time I do a make (a Java project) in IDEA, the compile process is hanging stating "Finished, saving caches". I have to kill this process before I can continue. I tried to use File -> Invalidate Caches without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird. U tried a machine restart? Check that the file location for your caches is writable? Does it happen on any IDEA project, or just one?

Comment: Machine restart did not help. I added more ram for the InteliJ JVM, but still it hangs... any ideas?

Comment: The problem and solution is described here in more detail:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625785/intellij-freezes-for-about-30-seconds-before-debugging

Comment: Is this on "Make" or is it on "Debug" which happens to do a make and then does a network connection to a newly spawned VM?  Because if on Debug, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625785/intellij-freezes-for-about-30-seconds-before-debugging since that is the real problem.

Answer (score 45):

One more workaround is adding your mac's hostname to `/etc/hosts` file along with localhost like the following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost <hostnameOfMac>
::1       localhost <hostnameOfMac>
```

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me, and I would *love* to know why on earth the hostname affects IntelliJ writing files to disk.

Comment: Tell me if you ever find out :)

Comment: This was driving me nuts - above solution worked - obviously name resolution is needed .. for some spurious reason!

Comment: WHY DOES IT WORK?!?!?!

Answer (score 6):

According to JetBrains,

> IntelliJ IDEA caches a great number of files, therefore the system cache may one day become overloaded. In certain situations the caches will never be needed again, for example, if you work with frequent short-term projects. Also, the only way to solve some conflicts is to clean out the cache.

Go to the menu **File | Invalidate Caches/Restart** and take it from there.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: How did this answer receive +6, when the never-edited OP clearly states _"I tried to use File -> Invalidate Caches without success."_

Answer (score 3):

I got this same problem after installing Bitdefender.
The suggestion with adding those lines in /etc/hosts doesn't solve it in my case.

Comment: OK, but how did you solve it? uninstall? maybe you had another solution?

Comment: My workaround was to disable the scan module which cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat as RBrink.  Company recently installed Bitdefender on all Macs and the hostname solution doesn't work.

Only workaround I've been able to use to get me past it is to simply **click the little 'X'** next to where is says "Finished, saving caches".  It's annoying, but it works.  Wish there was a better option, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine also had this problem during debugging (Intellij frozes on 'finished, updating caches'). His server was configured to  'update classes and resources' on the 'on frame deactivation' option. Once he set this option to 'Do nothing' he could switch to another program to look something up and continue to debug later on.

Answer (score 0):

Just based on circumstances, I get the impression it might be SBT related. When I have sbt running in intellij (to run a play server), I get this issue. If I restart intellij, the issue goes away.

Admittedly, its hard to prove this connection, but after three uses of this solution, it appears valid.

(The `hosts` solution did not work for me)

Answer (score 0):

@manyata-goyal 's solution worked for me.

Adding steps for those who are trying this on a Windows system:

- Get your hostname: Go to My PC -> Properties (System Properties) -> scroll down to 'Full computer name' -> copy the full computer name
- Edit hosts file: Go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` open `hosts` file
- Uncomment the lines and add hostname as mentioned in the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052722/3858467)