# IntelliJ freezes for about 30 seconds before debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

when i try to debug my java app the IDE freezes for about 30 seconds with the message:
"Finished, saving caches"

After it unfreezes all works fine. It happens every time.

When i only run (not debug) it does not freeze.

What i tried:

- I changed the JDK on system.
- I changed the IntelliJ version.
- I change to IntelliJ Ultimate - trial.
- Invalidating the IDE's cache.
- [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658400/intellij-idea-hangs-while-finished-saving-caches)
- I also figured out that the given message exists only it this area of code - [github-project](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Finished%2C%20saving%20caches) so i changed the JVM options to give InteliJ more ram.

InteliJ build IC-141.1010.3.

When i try to debug in other IDE's it works fine, only InteliJ gets stuck...

I submitted a ticket to jetbrains too, but i know the power of StackOverflow :)

I have a MacBookPro 2015 and JDK 1.8

Comment: The logs are stored in ~/.IntelliJIdea14/system/log/idea.log (there's a built-in log rotation). Seeing anything suspicious there?  By reviewing it, you can also be sure which java it is using. (On Mac, the location is rather different).

Comment: The logs indicated that there was a hang within java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.getLocalHostName(Native Method).

Comment: Awesome thanks for the hint, @fane89, I had the issue with the hostname as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception

Comment: The accepted answer is not the solution, the other answer is.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39971232/3679676  You can change the accepted answer to reflect this and help people out with the issue.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If anyone else is still having this problem, I found this related issue on the IntelliJ board: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157303

It seems the problem is related to resolving hostnames. The recommended workaround is to include the following line in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost     <your hostname goes here>.local
```

And for IPv6 resolving, the same:

```
::1             localhost     <your hostname goes here>.local
```

Comment: awesome. that was easy. I don't know what changed. it was working just last night.

Comment: Wow, great answer -  it's instant now. Much appreciated

Comment: After about 2 years of just putting up with it - this answer sorted it for me on macOS 10.12.4

Comment: Weird, that immediately fixed it—didn't even have to restart IntelliJ or computer. Thanks!

Comment: Just upgraded to macOS High Sierra. This still applies. Writing "hostname" in terminal gived you the hostname, and you can just add tab + your "hostname".local to the existing lines.

Comment: After months of suffering from this freeze, finally everything is back to normal on Mojave

Comment: I fixed by adding `127.0.0.1    <your hostname goes here>` without .local which fixed the problem

Answer (score 26):

Well, the issue took me around 3 hours to find out how to overcome it. For anyone has tried "modifying etc host file" solution from Jayson Minard and still not worked. Just go to SystemPreference -> Sharing and turn on File Sharing. That's on and it will let you debug your Java app on IntelijIdea 2017 very very very fast !!!!!!

[image]

Comment: This also worked for me. I wonder what this does behind the scenes for IntelliJ to launch debugging faster.

Comment: where is this option in windows 10?

Comment: dude, I logged in just write a 'thank you' comment. Take my upvote.

Comment: This made a very big difference. How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 8):

The support from IntelliJ told me to try the IDE with bundled java.

http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-14.1.3-custom-jdk-bundled.dmg

And it works!

**Edit:**

IntelliJ support feedback:
The problem was that there was a hang within `java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.getLocalHostName(Native Method)` JDK method call, which gets your system hostname. This is either JDK problem or local configuration issue...

**The solution for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception).**