# IntelliJ idea slow/hang during debug make phase

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently experiencing very slow debug start up times (between 25-45 seconds) with idea CE 14.1.5.  To reproduce:

- Make change in code that will cause javac to be invoked.
- Hit debug.
- Status bar shows "Make" and entire IDE hangs.

I'm using a 2015 Macbook pro and Java 1.8.0_60 64bit.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827577-Reporting-performance-problems

Answer (score 6):

After profiling with advice from above, I tracked it down to this issue:

[IntelliJ freezes for about 30 seconds before debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625785/intellij-freezes-for-about-30-seconds-before-debugging)

Which in turn points to an issue with `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` on *nix.  Following the advice in this linked post certainly helped it go away:

[InetAddress.getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception)

Comment: Shawn Lu's answer on the first linked post above sorted it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems of starting debugging application and tried different workaround tips to figure it out, but in my case i had a lot of forgotten breakpoints marked in application and removing them all application starts and performs lightening fast.

So, my advice remove all the breakpoints from the code at least at application startup.

Answer (score -3):

You should assign more memory. This almost always reduces lagging / hanging issues. You can find a guide how to change this setting in [IntelliJ manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html).

Comment: This was not a lag, or slowness, it completely freezes.   And issue was related to host name resolution.   See answers above.